# Express rate limiter Node JS - Error al asignar middleware

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, promesas, async-await

estoy intentando implementar rate limiter con "express-rate-limit", en el cual los parametros de WindowsMs y max son personalizados. La variable info simularía una llamada a la DB.

El problema es cuando hago el app.use("/api/",apiLimiter) no se asignan las variables al objeto response que es donde lleva la cuenta de las peticiones hechas. No se si es por que hasta ese momento la variable apiLimiter no se resolvió

```
    const express   = require('express');
    const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

    const app = express();

    let info = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(function(){
            let obj =  { 'minutes': 2, 'count' : 2}
            resolve(obj);
       }, 50);
    });

    async function obtenerDatos(){

       const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
           windowMs: parseInt((await info).minutes, 10) * 60 * 1000,
           max: parseInt((await info).count, 10),
           statusCode: 200,
           message: {
             status: 429,
             error: 'Too many requests, Please try again in 10 minutes.'
           },
           keyGenerator: async function (req, res) {
                  return req.ip    

           }


         }

        return apiLimiter;

     })

    const promesaObjeto = obtenerDatos();

    promesaObjeto.then( data =>{

      //aca le paso el objeto apiLimiter definido arriba. Deberia ser "data" o simplemente "apiLimiter"??

        app.use("/api/", data );

    });

    // ruta de ejemplo
    app.get('/api/index', (req, res)=> {
        /* aqui imprimo el obj response y deberian aparecer las sig. variables, PERO NO APARECEN:

           'x-ratelimit-limit': [ 'X-RateLimit-Limit', 2 ],
           'x-ratelimit-remaining': [ 'X-RateLimit-Remaining', 1 ],
           date: [ 'Date', 'Fri, 17 Apr 2020 20:27:03 GMT' ],
          'x-ratelimit-reset': [ 'X-RateLimit-Reset', 1587155343 ] }*/

         console.log(res)
         res.send("Show Index") 

    });

app.get('*', (req, res)=> {
  let response = {"error": "Route not found" }
  res.status(404).json(response);

});


// Starting the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('server on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

En el ejemplo de la libreria, los parametros estan fijos y asi no tengo problemas.

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

// Enable if you're behind a reverse proxy (Heroku, Bluemix, AWS ELB, Nginx, etc)
// see https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html
// app.set('trust proxy', 1);

const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100
});

// only apply to requests that begin with /api/
app.use("/api/", apiLimiter);
```

Alguna sugerencia? o que otra manera podria implementarlo ??? middleware a nivel de rutas??

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que pasa si intentas colocar esto:

```
// ruta de ejemplo
app.get('/api/index', (req, res)=> {
    /* aqui imprimo el obj response y deberian aparecer las sig. variables, PERO NO APARECEN:

       'x-ratelimit-limit': [ 'X-RateLimit-Limit', 2 ],
       'x-ratelimit-remaining': [ 'X-RateLimit-Remaining', 1 ],
       date: [ 'Date', 'Fri, 17 Apr 2020 20:27:03 GMT' ],
      'x-ratelimit-reset': [ 'X-RateLimit-Reset', 1587155343 ] }*/

     console.log(res)
     res.send("Show Index") 

});

app.get('*', (req, res)=> {
  let response = {"error": "Route not found" }
  res.status(404).json(response);

});
```

Dentro de:

```
promesaObjeto.then( data =>{

      //aca le paso el objeto apiLimiter definido arriba. Deberia ser "data" o simplemente "apiLimiter"??

        app.use("/api/", data );

});
```

Quedando así:

```
promesaObjeto.then( data =>{

    //aca le paso el objeto apiLimiter definido arriba. Deberia ser "data" o simplemente "apiLimiter"??
    app.use("/api/", data );

    // ruta de ejemplo
    app.get('/api/index', (req, res)=> {
        /* aqui imprimo el obj response y deberian aparecer las sig. variables, PERO NO APARECEN:

            'x-ratelimit-limit': [ 'X-RateLimit-Limit', 2 ],
            'x-ratelimit-remaining': [ 'X-RateLimit-Remaining', 1 ],
            date: [ 'Date', 'Fri, 17 Apr 2020 20:27:03 GMT' ],
            'x-ratelimit-reset': [ 'X-RateLimit-Reset', 1587155343 ] }*/

        console.log(res)
        res.send("Show Index") 

    });

    app.get('*', (req, res)=> {
        let response = {"error": "Route not found" }
        res.status(404).json(response);
    });

});
```

Ahora, si al hacer esto todo deja de funcionar o se comporta de manera extraña, significa que entonces, esta linea:

```
app.use("/api/", data );
```

Lastimosamente no puede ir dentro de la promesa y las demas tampoco, haciendo que tengas que reformular un poco el código para que sea sincrono.

Comment: Excelente!!!! si,  puse todo dentro de la Promesa y se asigno bien el middleware a las rutas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes iniciar tu server y los middleware luego de obtener el dato de la base de datos.

```
const express = require("express");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

const app = express();

let info = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function () {
    let obj = { minutes: 2, count: 2 };
    resolve(obj);
  }, 50);
});

async function obtenerDatos() {
  const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: parseInt((await info).minutes, 10) * 60 * 1000,
    max: parseInt((await info).count, 10),
    statusCode: 200,
    message: {
      status: 429,
      error: "Too many requests, Please try again in 10 minutes.",
    },
    keyGenerator: async function (req, res) {
      return req.ip;
    },
  });
  return apiLimiter;
}

obtenerDatos().then((data) => {
  //aca le paso el objeto apiLimiter definido arriba. Deberia ser "data" o simplemente "apiLimiter"??
  app.use("/api/", data);

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    let response = { error: "Route not found" };
    res.status(404).json(response);
  });

  // ruta de ejemplo
  app.get("/api/index", (req, res) => {
    /* aqui imprimo el obj response y deberian aparecer las sig. variables, PERO NO APARECEN:

           'x-ratelimit-limit': [ 'X-RateLimit-Limit', 2 ],
           'x-ratelimit-remaining': [ 'X-RateLimit-Remaining', 1 ],
           date: [ 'Date', 'Fri, 17 Apr 2020 20:27:03 GMT' ],
          'x-ratelimit-reset': [ 'X-RateLimit-Reset', 1587155343 ] }*/

    console.log(res);
    res.send("Show Index");
  });
  // Starting the server
  app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log("server on port", app.get("port"));
  });
});
```